# Spring transaction boundary extension

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a chain of method calls where A calls B that calls C that calls D. A and D have @Transactional annotation. but B and C doesn't.  what is the scope of transaction boundaries in this case. are B and C part of the transaction at all?

Comment: a) Are A, B, C, D in the same class? b) are you using JDK proxies(default), CGLib (proxy-target-class=true) or AspectJ (mode=aspectj)

Comment: no , they are in different classes. and i use Spring with default configuration.

Comment: re default config: that depends on whether your classes are backed by interfaces. Are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default A, B, C & D work in the same transaction. The default propagation level of a transaction is TX_REQUIRED meaning a new transaction is started if one does not exist (A starts one, B, C, D participates).

D could start a new transaction by setting its propagation level to TX_REQUIRES_NEW (if your environment supports it). In that scenario, when D is done the suspended transaction is resumed. Committing D does not affect the outcome of transaction A. Rollbacking A will not rollback D (already committed) as they are separate transactions.

Also, a lot of developers forgets that only public method may be marked @Transactional as Spring uses proxies to manage the transactions (private/protected methods are called on "this" - thus the proxy has no chance to do its magic). This does not necessiraly hold true if you are using byte code injection instead of proxies.

If you wish to learn more about transaction design patterns, I strongly suggest the following ebook (free! - registration required): http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/JTDS. It is a very straightforward read.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the [propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) parameter of the `@Transactional` annotation.

Per default, everything that happens within A is part of one single transaction - that includes all methods called directly and indirectly by it.

Other propagation mode would allow D to suspend the current transaction and start its own, execute in a nested transaction, or throw an exception because it's not meant to be used within an existing transaction.

Comment: I mean when B and C doesn't have any Annotation, do the default "Requires" is applied or ...?

Comment: There is one "simple" rule of thumb to understand in Transaction design: the object/method that starts the transaction is also responsible to determine the outcome (commit/rollback). In your scenario, A calls B -> C -> D before A is finished therefore they participate in A's transaction. B & C are not transaction aware as they don't have the annotation. D is a little different, by default it will check if there is an active transaction and participate. Otherwise it would start a new one.

Comment: @meisam: You're looking at it the wrong way. Transactions don't know about methods, only about access to transaction-aware resources like Databases. The annotation causes A to start a transaction before it executes, and afterwards every access to a transaction-aware resource that happens in that thread (no matter in which method) is part of the transaction until A finishes and commits or rolls back the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Independent of what happens:

if this question even comes up, you probably have serious design problems.

in 95% of cases, Transaction demarcation should take place at the entry point of your application, that is in a service method that calls all the other code internally.

The only valid case I can think of where one `@Transactional` method calls another is when the inner method has propagation `REQUIRES_NEW`. If that is not the case: refactor your design, so that your code only passes through a single `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: I agree 100%. The other scenario where @Transactional may be required on an inner method is to check that a transaction is active (TRX_MANDATORY): an exception is raised if none are found. We do this on our DAOs, so you cannot call a DAO directly, you have to go through the Service Layer (REQUIRES_NEW|REQUIRED).

Comment: @Patrick I agree about TRX_MANDATORY, that's the only TX annotation that makes sense on a DAO

Comment: I don't agree. what if C adds a Task to a Queue. and that task actually executes D? in that case you can't have them in the same transaction and you need to use REQUIRES_NEW for D. although this is not as direct as calling a DAO method.

Comment: @meisam if it adds a task to a queue, that sounds like an asynchroneous execution (using JMS, perhaps). In which case D should certainly not be executed from within A. Registered, perhaps, but not executed.

Comment: @Sean. thanks for your answer but It is not a JMS async task. it is a java Runnable Task.

Comment: @meisam yes, but that should be executed through a dedicated executor with its own transaction handling, not in the context of the original method

Comment: @Sean. exactly and there is the place that requires_new comes into the picture. we add the tasks in a transaction and execute them in another.

Comment: @meisam ??? but the execution should take place in a separate thread, which will have its own transactional context

Answer (score 1):

If you call B and C from a @Transactional A, they will still be in a transaction.

Have a look at [transaction propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation) in spring docs.